# How to find whether current Cursor region is bullet or not

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML code as below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="Editbox" contentEditable="true"  
        style="border: solid 1px red; width: 600px; height: 300px; 
        overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;">
        <ol style = "list-style-type:lower-alpha";>
        <li> hello </li>
        <li> how are you</li>
        </ol>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i am placing my  cursor after "are", i want to find which type of bullet it is. I mean style of the bullet, either orderlist or unorderedlist. How to find out the same.

Comment: not getting idea of placing cursor after "are"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "place my cursor after". Non form elements don't maintain a cursor position.

Comment: @Veena Sujith: Is it on mouseover 'you' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind an `onmouseover` event to `characterData` but you can wrap it in a span and bind to the span element.

```
<ol>
    <li/>
    <li>how are <span id="test">you</span></li>
    <li/>
</ol>

var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.onmouseover = function(){
    console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.tagName);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AsFvT/